# Is there a non-abelian group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a non-abelian group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ is abelian?  I have not been able to find an example.

Comment: Groupprops calls such a group Aut-abelian (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Aut-abelian_group).

Comment: Groupprops also has references describing nonabelian examples, which were apparently first constructed in 1913: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Aut-abelian_not_implies_abelian

Answer (score 12):

A non-abelian group can have an abelian group of isomorphisms (automorphisms).
An affirmative answer to this question was given by G. A. Miller  in 1913 . 
Title of the paper is "A non abelian group whose group of isomorphism is abelian"
He constructed a non-abelian group $G$ of order $64$ such that $Aut(G)$ is abelian and
has order $128$.

**Added** [In this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01229715#page-1) Author has defined  $p + 1$ non-isomorphic groups of order $p^8$ (for each $p$) whose automorphism groups are elementary abelian of order $p^{16}$.

[This link may also help you.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01899435#page-1)

Comment: Here is the complete reference: G. A. Miller, A non-abelian group whose group of isomorphisms is abelian. *Messenger Math.* 43, 124–125 (1913).